# Find conformal map $h$ from the circular sector common to circles $ | z-1| = 1$ and $ |z-i| = 1$ to the right-half plane. Find $h^{-1}(1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry, linear-fractional-transformation

I am trying to first construct a fractional linear transformation, to map the sector to a half or full circle. From there it seems straightforward using rotations, translations, and standard mappings between circles to half-planes to create a map that takes the sector to the right-half plane. [image: Image of sector]

My question is, how do I construct the fractional linear transformation? Lang's Complex Analysis shows how to construction fractional linear transformations to map a triplet of points to another triplet of points, but I don't see how that would be useful here.

Comment: Inversion ($z\to 1/z$) with center the origin will transform your region into a quadrant. Then you can bring its vertex to the origin and square to get a half plane. A translation perpendicular to the line defining the half plane and moving it such that the half plane doesn't contain the origin, followed by another inversion with respect to the origin, gives a disc.

Comment: @NDB Is that first part true though? The sector is not a full quarter circle, so how does inversion through unit circle give a full quadrant?

Comment: Note the tangents at $1+i$ are perpendicular, so this angle will be preserved. So these two circles are mapped to lines (since they will pass through $\frac1{1+i}$ and $\infty$) that are perpendicular

Comment: @MPW That makes sense. But how do you know the tangents at $1+i$ are perpendicular? Also, if that is true then the same can be said about the tangent lines at 0 correct?

Comment: Yes, the two lines into which the circles transform intersect perpendicularly at $\infty$ too. The tangents at the intersection points are, the axes for the origin and $x=1$ and $y=1$ for the other point.

Comment: @NDB. I came up with $( \frac{ 1}{z} - \frac{ 1}{2} + \frac{ i}{2} )^2 i$. The $ \frac{ 1}{z} $ gives a subset of the fourth quadrant with a corner at $ \frac{ 1}{2} - \frac{ i}{2}$. I then shift this to the origin by adding  $- \frac{ 1}{2} + \frac{ i}{2}$, giving the fourth quadrant. I then square this to get the lower-half plane, then multiply by $i$ to rotate 90 degrees, giving the right-half plane. Does this work?

Comment: Because $i$ and $1$ are the centers of the two circles. That means $1+i$ is the rightmost point of the upper circle and the topmost point of the lower circle. So the tangents there respectively are vertical and horizontal, which are perpendicular.

Comment: @MPW Makes sense. My own poor drawing prevented me from seeing that! Thank you.